# Why isn't "REISUB" working on Debian?

Tags: debian, kernel, reboot

I'm using Debian 'Jessie'. 
Sometimes my computer freezes, and then I can't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to reboot, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to kill the X Window System nor <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to open a new shell. I've read in several sites that in a computer freeze you can use the basic kernel commands that are used pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Sysreq</kbd> (holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Sysreq</kbd> and pressing REISUB one key)

But in my computer that 'trick' isn't working when it's frozen. Has the kernel frozen as well? I heard that one of the best things of Linux was that you never had to turn off the computer by holding the power button, but It's not being true for me :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Magic keys tend to be disabled in Debian these days, so you can't just hard-reboot your machine or kill all your X processes by pressing a few keys accidentally.

The X <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> key sequence is controlled by the "DontZap" option in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` -- man xorg.conf for more details. I think you want this, though:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "DontZap" "false"
EndSection
```

The <kbd>sysreq</kbd> keys are controlled by the kernel options during kernel compile time, boot time, and also sysctl options.  To enable it on Debian, put

```
kernel.sysrq=1
```

into `/etc/sysctl.conf`, and either reload that file (`sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`; man sysctl for more), or just edit the file and reboot.

Comment: I'm trying to edit the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file (with `nano`) but it says it's a new file (that file doesn't seem to exist there) I've also tried with the other locations specified in the man page, but I can't find the file.

Comment: @dieortin most modern systems don't have an `xorg.conf` file by default and instead set everything up using `udev`. You can simply create a new file at `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and edit that.