# How to power off normally after Debian crashed?

Tags: debian, reboot, crash

The keyboard did not work, but worked after I pressed Alt+SysRq+R. Then I pressed Alt+SysRq+B, and the computer did not reboot.
What else can I do?

I have found Ctrl+Alt+Delete will reboot the computer.

Answer (score 0):

If <kbd>Alt+SysRq+b</kbd> fails [it is probably disabled on your system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124397/3645). AFAIK you have no choice but to hard boot at that point.

Comment: Just now I found Ctrl+Alt+Delete works.