# Debian 10 with xfce freezes often without any trace

Tags: debian, freeze, crash, kernel-panic

I recently installed Debian 10 on my computer. I am using xfce as desktop environment with it.

Ever since it freezes often, without prior warning and without any traces in logs. I checked the /var/log folder, especially the messages and kernel logs, but no sign of any kernel panic or any error.

If the freeze occurs, I can't move the mouse, keyboard is not anymore responsive. And I also cannot switch to other tty. Also Ctrl + Alt + Del is not working then. Only "hard reset" or "graceless shutdown" works!

What can I do? How can I find out, what causes it? Maybe an application? Or a service?

Please help me! I don't have any idea.

Comment: Do you have another piece of hardware you can use to try to ssh into your host when it freezes?

Comment: Could you state your hardware setup? Ryzen processor by any chance? Does the REISUB-sequence work? [needs activation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124393/why-isnt-reisub-working-on-debian)

Comment: Any sign of overheating? Did you try running memtest86? Can you provoke a freeze while looking at a text mode virtual console? Or has your computer got a serial port?

Comment: Text mode console did not cause freeze. Memtest86 shows no error. No serial port available. No overheat (not warm).

Comment: I have the same situation here, Debian 10 with XFCE, freezes some time after usage, no clues. Memory (memtest) is OK. On Cinnamon it does not freeze. Today I turned off visual effects and I am going to see how it goes.

Comment: Thank You @diegov. I am looking forward for Your answers.

Comment: @A.V., after shutting down the visual effects, the problem went away! I shut down everything, so I don't know exactly which one was the culprit :P

Comment: @diegov, how did you disable all visual effects? I had an issue with lockout not working so I uninstalled a package that was directed on a different recommendation, now I no longer get locked out, but the whole XFCE will just freeze for some time, it will eventually come back (5min or so?) but it would be nice to never freeze at all. I'm not OP, but ALT+CTRL+F1 does allow me to switch away from XFCE to a command prompt, so what logs can I check to find the culprit?